# new php facebook library reuse session

Tags: php, facebook, api

I accidentally overwrote the Facebook PHP library with the new up-to-date one, damage has been done as my complete system is now broken.

The problem is, I have no clue how the new authentication process works, at first you would get a signed_response (or something similar) containing the expiration, oauth_key, oauth_secret and accesstoken after the user authenticates the app,
Now however I only get the parameters 'state' and 'code'.

Can anyone explain to me how I have to reconfigure my app to use these parameters to reuse a user-session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate Facebook API too, its like... monkey :P
You can use in SDK 3

```
$facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Save the hash in database and later use

```
$facebook->setAccessToken('...');
```

http://qpleple.com/get-and-use-facebook-offline_access-tokens/

You need pre configure to off "Remove offline_access permission" in config of app in facebook developer page.

If you want use this session in Javascript send email to GOD :P

Comment: seems to work :) I was so stupid to put my scope in the old facebook library so that got erased too, got it working now :) thanks!

Comment: nice! :D If you discover how use facebook Access Token of PHP in JS, please contact me twitter.com/leifsk8er ;)